# Seperating overlapping wrapfigures

Tags: wrapfigure, block

How do I separate these two wrapfigure elements?

[image]

I wish for the second wrapfigure to start after the length of the first wrapfigure  length. Instead, they merge into each other. The  second wrapfigure starts from where the first wrapfigure ends.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

my code:

```
\begingroup
\begin{wrapfigure}[50]{r}[1cm]{0.55\textwidth}
\centering
  \caption{Sidebar menu detailed view.}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{close-up-menu.pdf}
\end{wrapfigure}

lipsum[1]

\endgroup

\begingroup
\begin{wrapfigure}[50]{r}[1cm]{0.55\textwidth}
\centering
  \caption{Sidebar menu detailed view.}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{date-close-up.pdf}
\end{wrapfigure}

lipsum[1]

\endgroup
```

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  When I run your test case (after completing it) with `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` they are not overlapping. However, if you want one figure below the other wouldn't it make sense to put them in the _same_ `wrapfigure` environment?

Comment: If the text is shorter than the figure, you are better off using minipages and \captionof{figure}.  Otherwise you have to use \WFclear and skip an unknown distance to bet past the  figure.

Comment: Wrapfigures are nice if you have figures of width much smaller than the text width because they allow you to avoid wasting space. However, in your example you might be better off if you just put these figures horizontally next to each other.